# Quantum on hash

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, post-quantum-cryptography

Perhaps this has been answered before. Grover's algorithm should result in a 256 bit hash being complexity 128 bits to crack.

I was wondering, what if you had a 512 bit hash , and xor'd the lower 256 with the upper 256 bits to result in a final 256 bit hash number.

Does this increase the complexity (ie: decreasing the viability of Grover's algorithm) by any factor?

I'm expecting not, however was just theorizing how you could remap a 512 bit hash into a 256 bit space to stop grovers from functioning (reminiscent of some public key compression algorithms).

Comment: Best case it's just another 256-bit hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grover's algorithm treats the function it is evaluating as a black box and finds, with high probability, an input to the black box such that it outputs a specified value in $O(N^{1/2})$ evaluations of the function.

Since Grover's algorithm works on the function as a black box, your modification does not hinder Grover's algorithm at all in finding the preimage.